# dynamic change url flash builder

Tags: string, flash-builder, dynamic-url

I am trying to create app with list of word and sound for every one of this word 
XML

```
<bla>
   <list>
         <word>Hello</word>
         <audio>Hello.mp3</audio>
   </list>
   <list>
         <word>Bye</word>
         <audio>bye.mp3</audio>
   </list>
</bla>
```

SOURCE :

```
<s:navigationContent>
        <s:Button label="Listan" click="playSound();"/>
</s:navigationContent>
```

Script :

```
<fx:Script>
     <![CDATA[
            import flash.media.*;

            [Embed(source="assent/sounds/{data.audio}")]

            [Bindable]
            public var sndCls:Class;
            public var snd:Sound = new sndCls() as Sound; 
            public var sndChannel:SoundChannel;

            public function playSound():void {
                sndChannel=snd.play();
            }   
            public function stopSound():void {
                sndChannel.stop();
            }   
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
```

I have error here :

```
[Embed(source="assent/sounds/{data.audio}")]
```

Error message :

```
Unable to transcode {data.audio}.
```

What can I do to fix it :} 
Using Flash Builder 4.6

Answer (score 0):

Embed = compiler directive. Embed haven't any runtime abilities at all. You must embed all assets or load it dynamically...